# Pandas Dataframe - How To Convert Date to Boolean Columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been stumped for quite a while on a simple data transformation, and I am hoping the hive mind can assist.

Suppose I have a Python Pandas dataframe used for machine learning built as follows:

```
>> trainingDF.ix[0:3,'temp']

Index                   temp
2011-01-01 00:00:00     9.84
2011-01-01 01:00:00     9.02
2011-01-01 02:00:00     9.02
```

We see the index is a pandas datatime series, and the singular data column is the temperature.

I would like to add 12 feature columns to this dataframe, each one indicating if the sample (E.g. row) is a given month.  In other words, it should look as follows:

```
Index                   temp     isJan isFeb isMar isApr isMay etc.
2011-01-01 00:00:00     9.84     1     0     0     0     0     etc.
2011-01-01 01:00:00     9.02     1     0     0     0     0     etc.
2011-01-01 02:00:00     9.02     1     0     0     0     0     etc.
```

Unfortunately, despite a number of disparate attempts, I cannot seem to pin down an elegant way to accomplish this.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `get_dummies` to do the hard work.  Something like

```
target = pd.DataFrame(0, index=df.index, columns=range(1,13))
dm = pd.get_dummies(df.index.month).set_index(df.index)
target = (target + dm).fillna(0)
target.columns = ['is'+x.capitalize() for x in pd.datetools.MONTHS]
pd.concat([df, target], axis=1)
```

produces

```
                temp  isJan  isFeb  isMar  isApr  isMay  isJun  isJul  isAug  \
2011-01-01  0.419860      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
2011-03-22  0.479502      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0   
2011-06-10  0.687352      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0   
2011-08-29  0.377993      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1   
2011-11-17  0.877410      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   

            isSep  isOct  isNov  isDec  
2011-01-01      0      0      0      0  
2011-03-22      0      0      0      0  
2011-06-10      0      0      0      0  
2011-08-29      0      0      0      0  
2011-11-17      0      0      1      0
```

---

Some explanation follows.

First, let's make a test frame:

```
>>> index = pd.date_range("2011-01-01", periods=5, freq="80d")
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"temp": np.random.random(5)}, index=index)
>>> df
                temp
2011-01-01  0.566277
2011-03-22  0.965421
2011-06-10  0.854030
2011-08-29  0.780752
2011-11-17  0.148783
```

Now let's make something that has the right shape as what we want (we shouldn't assume that we'll necessarily see every month, after all; our test example only has 5 months with nonzero values):

```
>>> target = pd.DataFrame(0, index=df.index, columns=range(1,13))
>>> target
            1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
2011-01-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-03-22   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-06-10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-08-29   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-11-17   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

`get_dummies` will generate an indicator matrix:

```
>>> dm = pd.get_dummies(df.index.month).set_index(df.index)
>>> dm
            1   3   6   8   11
2011-01-01   1   0   0   0   0
2011-03-22   0   1   0   0   0
2011-06-10   0   0   1   0   0
2011-08-29   0   0   0   1   0
2011-11-17   0   0   0   0   1
```

(And now you can see why we wanted to have the missing columns somewhere.)  We can add these two together:

```
>>> target = (target + dm).fillna(0)
>>> target
            1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
2011-01-01   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-03-22   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-06-10   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-08-29   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
2011-11-17   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

And we're all done except for making it look pretty.  There are lots of ways to get month names; let's choose one at random:

```
>>> pd.datetools.MONTHS
['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']
>>> target.columns = ['is'+x.capitalize() for x in pd.datetools.MONTHS]
```

And now the columns are named as you wanted.  All that remains is to combine everything:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, target], axis=1)
                temp  isJan  isFeb  isMar  isApr  isMay  isJun  isJul  isAug  \
2011-01-01  0.566277      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
2011-03-22  0.965421      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0   
2011-06-10  0.854030      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0   
2011-08-29  0.780752      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1   
2011-11-17  0.148783      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   

            isSep  isOct  isNov  isDec  
2011-01-01      0      0      0      0  
2011-03-22      0      0      0      0  
2011-06-10      0      0      0      0  
2011-08-29      0      0      0      0  
2011-11-17      0      0      1      0
```